# Creating a Grid in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jlabel

As a way of learning Java, I'm writing this little application for grade schoolers to practice basic math. The idea is that the kid does any number of math problems, as long as they are in the app, it just continues to throw problems at them until they click a 'Done' button. When they decide to be done, I want a new JFrame to come up that will show them all of the problems they attempted, along with their answer, and whether they got the problem right or wrong.

The advice that I am looking for is what is the best way for me present these results. I looked into the GridLayout and the GroupLayout, but I don't think that these are exactly right. I did something similar in VBA for Excel, and there I just ran a for loop with one iteration for every problem they attempted. Each iteration would add a row of labels to the frame with the elements of the problem displayed in the various labels. I tried this in Java, but I'm not even able to get the labels to even display.

So before I get all specific and start posting my code, I want to ask a bigger question, which is "what is the best method to create a view like this?" Often, I go off in one direction only to waste time before somebody suggests a totally different (and better) approach.

Thanks!

(edit: here's an image of how I did this in Excel. I'm trying to repeat basically the same thing in Java)

[image]

Comment: Since it's the outcome of the user interaction, with the application, anyone will suggest you that, don't let a new `JFrame` to come up to show results to the user, instead use a `JDialog` or use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to shift between different `JPanel`s showing different views of the Application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One simple way to make that design would be to use a mix of components.  You could have a bunch of `JLabel`s and `JPanel`s stacked in a vertical `FlowLayout`.  The grid you have described would be best designed in a `JTable`, something like the below:

[image: example breakdown of components with gaudy colors]

Answer (score 7):

If you like tables like Excel then, Java provides `JTable` class to create tables, if you want.

Tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really looking for something that resembles a spreadsheet. I just used Excel since the programming was relatively easy.