# How to get proper alignment of Title border over the Jtable

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to build small application in java swings. I started using this link: [Creating a Grid in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304073/java-swing-creating-a-grid).

Everything was good. I finished that task but onething is left that I'm trying to remove extra title border. I tried to reduce the border of title border still its not affect. Any one with good suggestion try to share with me.

```
    package swings.application.framework;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent

;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Inf3rNix
 */
public class KidsProblemTable {
 private static JButton okbtn;

           private static     JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

         frame = new JFrame("Kids Table");


                Border border = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();
                frame.setLayout(null);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JLabel Heading = new JLabel("My Result");
                Heading.setFont(new Font("Gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 56));
                Heading.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                Heading.setBounds(550, -60, 300, 200);

                JLabel Heading2 = new JLabel("Nice Job! Here are your results...");
                Heading2.setFont(new Font("Buxton Sketch", Font.ITALIC, 26));
                Heading2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                Heading2.setBounds(500, 10, 600, 200);

                JLabel Heading3 = new JLabel();

                String str = "You got 5 correct answer out of 7 question";
                Heading3.setText("<html><a href=' ' style='color:rgb(248,116,49);'>" + str + "</a></html>");
                Heading3.setFont(new Font("Andy", Font.PLAIN, 20));

                Heading3.setBounds(500, 70, 600, 200);
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                Border border1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Exercise");



                panel1.setBounds(150, 200, 1000, 190);

                String column = "Questions".toUpperCase();

                //  AttributedString as = new AttributedString(column);
                //    Font plainFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24);
                //   as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, plainFont);
                //  as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON,0,8 );
                String column1 = "Problem".toUpperCase();
                String column2 = "Answer".toUpperCase();
                String column3 = "Answer".toUpperCase();
                String results = "results".toUpperCase();

                Object rowData[][] = {{"1", "3+9", "12", "12", "Correct !"},
                    {"2", "4+3", "7", "7", "Correct !"},
                    {"3", "10+8", "17", "18", "Sorry :("},
                    {"4", "5+1", "6", "6", "Correct !"},
                    {"5", "10+8", "18", "18", "Correct !"},
                    {"6", "8+2", "10", "10", "Correct !"},
                    {"7", "5+6", "4", "11", "Sorry :("}
                };
                Object columnNames[] = {column, column1, column2, column3, results};

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
                JTable tb1 = new JTable(model) {


                    //when checking if a cell is editable always return false



                    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                        return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
                    }

                };
                //JTable table1 = new JTable(rowData, columnNames1);
                tb1.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(153, 0, 91));


                JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(tb1);
                Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
                Border loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
                Border raisedetched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);
             //  ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/wavy.gif", "wavy-line border icon");


              okbtn=new JButton("Press Ok to Exit");
                           okbtn.setBorder(raisedbevel);

              okbtn.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.BOLD, 12));
                okbtn.setBounds(575, 390, 150, 50);
                panel2.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                okbtn.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener());
                frame.add(Heading);
                frame.add(Heading2);
                frame.add(Heading3);
                frame.add(okbtn);
                frame.add(panel1);

                panel2.setBorder(border1);
                panel1.add(panel2);

                frame.setSize(500, 500);



                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
    }

    private static class buttonActionListener implements ActionListener {



        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if(ae.getSource()==okbtn){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All the best !!!");
            WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING );
             Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent( winClosingEvent );

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` Is where the problems begin..

Comment: Thank you Andrew for point out my  mistake. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem,
You added the scrollPane to panel2 as

```
panel2.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

but you didn't setLayout as BorderLayout for panel2.
and you set the Layout of panel1 as null
see this code

```
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setLayout(null);//add to your code
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//add to your code
            panel2.setBounds(0,0,800,120);//add to your code
```

out put:

may this image will remove after some hours
[out put image](http://i45.tinypic.com/d403.jpg)

Comment: have you seen the image that i put on my post

Comment: Actually Exercise title border should not hold OK button. But i corrected that in my code. Finally i got the output ty padman.

Answer (score 2):

maybe

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Inf3rNix
 */
public class KidsProblemTable {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    private JLabel Heading = new JLabel("My Result", JLabel.CENTER);
    private JLabel Heading2 = new JLabel("Nice Job! Here are your results...", JLabel.CENTER);
    private JLabel Heading3 = new JLabel();
    private String str = "You got 5 correct answer out of 7 question";
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    private JButton okbtn;
    private Object rowData[][] = {{"1", "3+9", "12", "12", "Correct !"},
        {"2", "4+3", "7", "7", "Correct !"},
        {"3", "10+8", "17", "18", "Sorry :("},
        {"4", "5+1", "6", "6", "Correct !"},
        {"5", "10+8", "18", "18", "Correct !"},
        {"6", "8+2", "10", "10", "Correct !"},
        {"7", "5+6", "4", "11", "Sorry :("}
    };
    private String column = "Questions".toUpperCase();
    private String column1 = "Problem".toUpperCase();
    private String column2 = "Answer".toUpperCase();
    private String column3 = "Answer".toUpperCase();
    private String results = "results".toUpperCase();
    private Object columnNames[] = {column, column1, column2, column3, results};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    private JTable tb1 = new JTable(model) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //when checking if a cell is editable always return false
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
        }
    };
    private JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(tb1);

    public KidsProblemTable() {
        Border border1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Exercise");
        Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        tb1.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(153, 0, 91));
        tb1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tb1.getPreferredSize());
        Heading.setFont(new Font("Gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 56));
        Heading.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Heading2.setFont(new Font("Buxton Sketch", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        Heading2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Heading3.setText("<html><a href=' ' style='color:rgb(248,116,49);'>" + str + "</a></html>");
        Heading3.setFont(new Font("Andy", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        panel1.add(Heading);
        panel1.add(Heading2);
        panel1.add(Heading3);
        //  ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/wavy.gif", "wavy-line border icon");
        okbtn = new JButton("     Press Ok to Exit    ");
        okbtn.setBorder(raisedbevel);
        okbtn.setFont(new Font("Vani", Font.BOLD, 12));
        okbtn.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener());
        panel2.add(okbtn);
        panel2.setBorder(border1);
        frame = new JFrame("Kids Table");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class buttonActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            if (ae.getSource() == okbtn) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All the best !!!");
                WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KidsProblemTable();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Pity the OP choose the option (`setBounds(..)`) that will result in their **next 5** questions. :(

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks I posted my answer to already accepted question